# Future raising TypeError after wait

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to optimise an expensive operation in some existing code using parallel processing. I've used `concurrent.futures` to do so in the past but only when they didn’t return anything.

This time I want to marshall the results, but when printing my collection I'm getting every future's status as something like `<Future at 0x... state=finished raised TypeError>`. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
import concurrent.futures

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

  def _future(self) -> None:
    print("here")

  futures = []
  for number in list(range(0,100)):
    future = executor.submit(_future)
    futures.append(future)

  finished = concurrent.futures.wait(futures, 5)
  print(finished)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `_future` function takes one parameter, and yet your `executor.submit` is passing no argument to it. You should pass, for example, `number`, as an argument to it instead:

```
for number in list(range(0,100)):
    future = executor.submit(_future, number)
    futures.append(future)
```

On the other hand, since you're naming `_future`'s one parameter as `self`, it implies you intend it to be an instance of a class, in which case you should pass to it the proper instance object in your original, non-minimized code.

Comment: Ah! Yeah, I’d got confused with some existing code that was part of a class structure, this fixes my issue. Thanks!